# Can the rank of a matrix increase in a linear transformation?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

My initial thought is no: when multiplying a matrix by another matrix or vector, the number of pivot points either stays the same or decreases. Does anybody have an example of when it increases after a transformation? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This immediately follows from the standard theorem about ranks of products: they cannot be higher than that of either factor.